# Ruby Version Failure 2.7.0: Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/share/Library/

Tags: ruby, rvm

As the title states, when I try install Ruby version 2.7.0 with `rvm install ruby-2.7.0`, I get the following output:

```
Ruby Version Failure 2.7.0: Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/share/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/npm-micromatch-3.1.10-70859bc95c9840952f359a068a3fc49f9ecfac23-integrity/node_modules/micromatch/lib/.DS_Stor
```

The full output is below:

```
==> Upgrading 3 outdated packages:
libtool 2.4.6_1 -> 2.4.6_2
libyaml 0.2.2 -> 0.2.5
pkg-config 0.29.2_2 -> 0.29.2_3
==> Upgrading libtool 2.4.6_1 -> 2.4.6_2
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libtool-2.4.6_2.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/af317b35d0a394b7ef55fba4950735b0392d9f31bececebf9c412261c23a01fc?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22libtool-2.4.6_2.catalina.b
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring libtool-2.4.6_2.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
In order to prevent conflicts with Apple's own libtool we have prepended a "g"
so, you have instead: glibtool and glibtoolize.
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.6_2: 71 files, 3.7MB
==> `brew cleanup` has not been run in 30 days, running now...
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.6_1... (71 files, 3.7MB)
Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/share/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/npm-micromatch-3.1.10-70859bc95c9840952f359a068a3fc49f9ecfac23-integrity/node_modules/micromatch/lib/.DS_Store
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to rvm itself. To install required dependencies for your ruby, rvm used your installed homebrew. However, during cleanup of your installed bottles, homebrew encounters an error, possible because you one installed things with `sudo` previously.

Try `brew doctor` and follow its advice to fix your homebrew setup.